# WCF 4.5 Web service hosted on IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2012 gives an exception

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, .net-4.5

I am getting a ProtocolException when using a WCF Service targeting .NET framework 4.5 on IIS7.5 on a Windows Server 2012 box.

The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Any pointers to the problem would help as it works okay in Development env.

I can browse to the service's svc file in the browser but when invoked from a website on the same box, it gives this error.

Comment: Can you call it using another client, like SoapUI or a ConsoleApp?

Comment: @nvoigt Yes tried a console app and it did work!!

Comment: Could you specify what binding are you using in wcf service?

Comment: I am using basichttpsbinding